# in arbitrary metric space, nowhere dense set

Tags: general-topology

If 
$x_n\to x$
 in $\mathbb R$ 
, then the set $\{x\}\cup\{x_n \colon n\ge 1\}$ 
 is nowhere dense in
$\mathbb R$
.  What condition should be imposed on a metric space $M$ so that the same remains true; i.e., the range of any convergent sequence in it is nowhere dense?  I think the space should be T2 and there must be something in addition.

Comment: Every metric space is T2.  Do you mean *topoogical space* M?

Comment: Yes, if there is something for topological space you can tell .and also tell what should we impose on metric space..

Answer (score 0):

This is true for a metric space $M$ if and only if $M$ has no isolated points.

Clearly, if $M$ has an isolated point $x$, then the image of the constant sequence $x,x,x,\dots$ is *not* nowhere dense in $M$.

Conversely, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $M$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $\{x\}\cup\{x_n\colon n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not nowhere dense.  Suppose moreover that $x$ is not an isolated point.  Since $\{x\}\cup\{x_n\colon n\in \mathbb N\}$ is closed, this means that it has non-empty interior.

Let $U=\text{int}(\{x\}\cup\{x_n\colon n\in\mathbb N\})$.  By hypothesis, $U$ is non-empty, and so it must contain $x_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n\neq x$ (indeed, if it contains $x$, then it must contain infinitely many other points of the sequence, one of which must be not equal to $x$ since $x$ is not isolated).  By the definition of an open set, there must be some open ball $B_r(x_n)\subset U$.

Let $R=d(x_n,x)$.  Then there is some $N$ such that for all $m\ge N$ we have $d(x_m,x)<R/2$ (by the definition of a convergent sequence).

Let
$$
r' = \min\left(\{r, R/2\}\cup\{d(x_n,x_j)\colon j<N\}\right)
$$
noting that the RHS is a finite set so has a well defined minimum.  Then $r'\le r$ and so $B_{r'}(x_n)\subset U$.  Moreover, we see that $x_k\not\in B_{r'}(x_n)$ for $k\neq n$.  Now, since
$$
B_{r'}(x_n)\subseteq B_r(x_n)\subseteq U\subseteq \{x\}\cup\{x_n\colon n\in\mathbb N\}
$$
we see that $B_{r'}(x_n)=\{x_n\}$; i.e., $x_n$ is an isolated point in $M$.

It follows that if $M$ has *no* isolated points, then the image of any convergent sequence in $M$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Let $X=(\mathbb N,\tau)$ where $U\in\tau$ iff (1) $U=\emptyset,$ or (2) $\mathbb N\setminus U$ is finite, or (3) $1\notin U$ and $\mathbb N\setminus U$ has asymptotic density zero. Then $X$ is a $\text{T}_1$ space, and convergent sequences have unique limits: if $x\ne1$ then any sequence converging to $x$ is eventually constant. However, the sequence $x_n=n$ converges to $1,$ and $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}=\mathbb N$ is not nowhere dense.

Comment: On the other hand, I believe you were right about the generalization to Hausdorff spaces.